# Redirect subdomain using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, amazon-ec2, subdomain

I have a EC2 instance and host several sites on the server. I can redirect different domains to their specific folders but I cannot seem to redirect subdomains.

Here is my code so far for www.domain1.com which directs to "folder1" and retains the "www.domain1.com" address in the address bar - This is working fine:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} domain1.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/folder1
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ folder1/$1 [L]
```

However I cannot find a solution for sub-domains - I've tried many solutions similar to this - this does not work:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} sub.domain1.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/folder2
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ folder2/$1 [L]
```

I want http://sub.domain1.com to point to "folder2" but retain sub.domain1.com in the address bar. One thing I want to avoid is using my very long EC2 instance static address  "http://ec2-12-34-567-890.compute-1.amazonaws.com/" in the code if this is possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the host part to have boundaries:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain1\.com$ [NC]
```

and

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.domain1\.com$ [NC]
```

The first rule is matching against the host `sub.domain1.com` because it contains a `domain1.com`